# Laravel Eloquent relationship order by not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I store Event and Event Schedules are tow different Tables. I Display Event by Event Schedule Date Ascending. I use the following Query Its not Display Correctly.

```
 $eventslist=Events::with(['eventschedule' => function($query) {  $query->orderBy('eventdate', 'ASC'); }])->paginate($this->recordsperpage);
```

In Event Model :

```
public function eventschedule(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Eventshcedule','events_id','id')->orderBy('eventdate', 'ASC');

    }
```

[image]

I need to display events by Date wise asending.

Comment: I think your query is right, so what do u think  it is wrong?can u give a example

Comment: @TsaiKoga I Edited and updated the Question

Comment: can u post your view code?

Comment: because i am not sure about that one of the cards is a event or eventshedule

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below query?

```
$eventslist = Events::whereHas('eventschedule')->orderBy('eventdate')->paginate($this->recordsperpage);
```

Comment: $events_id is undefined Variable

Comment: `whereHas('eventschedule', function ($q) use ($events_id) {
  $q->where('id', $events_id);
})` is just an alias for having a relationship in the `event` model. Outcome will, unfortunately, remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

`function($query) {  $query->orderBy('eventdate', 'ASC')` will order the schedules by ascending order instead of its parent `event`.

Given that your events has **many** schedules, you'll need to select the **earliest** schedule, then order the events by that schedule.

The subsequent query that will return the required result is:

```
$eventScheduleTableName = App\Eventshcedule::getTable();

//Query fetches the schedules with the earliest dates
$minEventScheduleQuery = App\Eventshcedule::query()
                        ->select('id', DB::raw ('MIN(eventdate) as minEventDate'))
                        ->groupBy('id');

//Event query joins on schedule query, which allows an ordering by earliest schedule dates
//function `joinSub` is available as from laravel 5.6

$eventResult = Event::query()
                ->joinSub($minEventScheduleQuery, 'eventSchedule', function ($join) {
                    $join->on(Event::getQualifiedKeyName(),'=', "eventSchedule." Event::eventsschedule()->getForeignKey());
                })
                ->orderBy('eventSchedule.minEventDate', 'ASC')
                ->paginate($this->recordsperpage);
```